# Populating stateless child component props from parent component state to display nested unordered list in React (with Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I'm probably missing something very simple here, but I can't get my code to run properly. I'm trying to display a nested unordered list of `referenceListItems` for every `referenceList`. The main question I guess is how do I pass the state variable `referenceListItems` into the child component `ReferenceListItems`?

```
const ReferencePage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Reference</h1>
    <Reference />
  </div>
);

class ReferenceBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      referenceLists: [],
      referenceListItems: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onListenForReferenceLists();
    this.onListenForReferenceListItems();
  }

  onListenForReferenceLists() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    this.unsubscribeReferenceLists = this.props.firebase
      .referenceLists()
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.size) {
          let referenceLists = [];
          snapshot.forEach(doc =>
            referenceLists.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id }),
          );
          this.setState({
            referenceLists: referenceLists,
            loading: false
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ referenceLists: null, loading: false });
        }
    });
  }

  onListenForReferenceListItems() {
    this.unsubscribeReferenceListsItems = this.props.firebase
      .referenceListItems()
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.size) {
          let referenceListItems = [];
          snapshot.forEach(doc =>
            referenceListItems.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id }),
          );
          this.setState({
            referenceListItems: referenceListItems,
            loading: false
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ referenceListItems: null, loading: false });
        }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeReferenceLists();
    this.unsubscribeReferenceListsItems();
  }

  render() {
    const { referenceLists, referenceListItems, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loading && <div>Loading ...</div>}
        {referenceLists ? (
          <ReferenceLists referenceLists={referenceLists} />
        ):(
          <div>There are no reference items ...</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Reference = withFirebase(ReferenceBase);

const ReferenceLists = ({ referenceLists }) => (
  <ul className="reference-lists">
    {referenceLists.map( referenceList => (
      <ReferenceList key={referenceList.uid} referenceList={referenceList} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const ReferenceList = ({ referenceList }) => (
  <li className="reference">
    <strong>{referenceList.userId}</strong> {referenceList.name}
    <ReferenceListItems />
  </li>
);

const ReferenceListItems =({ referenceListItems }) => (
  <ul className="reference-list-items">
    {referenceListItems.map( referenceListItem => (
      <ReferenceListItem key={referenceListItem.uid} referenceListItem={referenceListItem} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const ReferenceListItem = ({ referenceListItem }) => (
  <li className="reference-list-item">
    <strong>{referenceListItem.userId}</strong> {referenceListItem.name}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: Is ReferenceListItems defined in another file?

Comment: No, I would like to avoid making another class for it, since it's just a really simple display. It's a stateless component right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not explicitly use your `ReferenceListItems` inside the parent `ReferenceBase` component. So you'll just have to pass it down as a property throughout the component tree.

```
  render() {
    const { referenceLists, referenceListItems, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loading && <div>Loading ...</div>}
        {referenceLists ? (
          <ReferenceLists referenceLists={referenceLists} referenceListItems={referenceListItems} />
        ):(
          <div>There are no reference items ...</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

### ReferenceLists

```
const ReferenceLists = ({ referenceLists, referenceListItems }) => (
  <ul className="reference-lists">
    {referenceLists.map( referenceList => (
      <ReferenceList key={referenceList.uid} referenceList={referenceList} referenceListItems={referenceListItems} />
    ))}
  </ul>
```

### ReferenceList

```
const ReferenceList = ({ referenceList, referenceListItems }) => (
  <li className="reference">
    <strong>{referenceList.userId}</strong> {referenceList.name}
    <ReferenceListItems referenceListItems={referenceListItems}/>
  </li>
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you suggest this approach? (it does seem kinda tedious)

Comment: you could've swapped the parameter of the compoents to make your answer look different. I don't see the difference between your answer and the one which was poested before yours.

Comment: @Pim. You're very welcome! Looking at the way you've setup these components, I think this would be the easiest solution to implement. You could also look into the React.Context api: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. This lets you pass in props from a HOC to deeply nested child-components without having to pass it down tediously. But, this would force you to rethink your component tree.

Comment: @TenTenPeter Christopher asked some questions in comment first, that's why I accepted his answer over the other one. Also, the answer is more complete.

Comment: @Pim, thanks for the feedback, did the solution above work for you?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo It did, but I'm running into some other problems when adding more functionality. Might have to declare `ReferenceListItems` as a full-fledged component.

Comment: @Pim ahh I see. I figured ReferenceListItems would eventually need to manage its own-state and etc. Probably will need to make it a class-component. In any case, passing props to it should be the same.

Comment: @Pim also instead of passing data down as props, use redux it's easy to implement https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: @Pim I was just stating the obvious, I don't have a problem with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

By redeclaring referenceList

```
let referenceLists = [];
```

it never gets set in your class. you either need to return the referenceLists inside the closure or set the class level variable in your callback

```
this.referenceLists.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id })
```

Comment: It does get set in the render call (if that's what you mean). I'm having no problem displaying the refenceLists, only the sub-items.

Comment: sorry my mistake I think [this](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17)  is what you are looking for